# Unable to write commands onto an exe program on shared location using java

Tags: java, exe, runtime.exec

I've an exe program placed on shared location. It doesn't take any arguments while starting. When it is launched in a command window, it displays a help menu with list of commands that can be executed with it and ends with `>` expecting an input command. I need to execute one particular command called `TRIGGER` from that list. So far this is what I've but it fails completely. It neither displays the output from the process nor takes the input command `trigger` from the stream.

```
public void execute(){

    String cmd = "\\\\sharedLocation\\server\\adm.exe";
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

    bw.write("TRIGGER");            
    bw.flush();

    String output = "";
    while (!output.endsWith(">")) {     
        System.out.println("in loop");
        output = output + br.readLine(); 
    }

    System.out.println("Out"+output);


    out.close();            
    p.waitFor();
}
```

**EDIT** : adm.exe is launched by this program but it appears that adm.exe is a blocking process. It fails to println the "in loop" statement. However when I open up windows task manager and kill the adm.exe process tree, this shows up on the console

```
in loopnull
in loopnullnull
in loopnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
in loopnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
Outnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Comment: You need to read the char don't you? (in.read()...)

Comment: Definitively `flush` bw. It will buffer the `TRIGGER` otherwise. In fact, I shouldn't use BufferedWriter. Just OSWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general comments:

1. Don't use `Process`, use `ProcessBuilder` instead. And if you want to do something more complex than starting an external process, use [Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html).
2. What happens if you just type `TRIGGER` on the command line without pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>? If nothing happens, press return from Java, too: Wrap `out` in a `PrintStream` and use `pw.println("TRIGGER")`
3. Since you don't get any output, maybe the command notices that it's not being started from a command prompt and behaves differently? If that's the case, run it with `cmd /c \\\\sharedLocation\\server\\adm.exe`
4. Always use lists/arrays to supply command arguments to avoid problems with special characters

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but...

**Timing**

I understand that your execute method gets blocked at `while` waiting for some output and its finalization. It will not came until you send TRIGGER.

I would try to

1. Send TRIGGER before (you will not lose any data, it gets buffered)
2. At the end of method use `p.waitFor()` to avoid exiting until p finishes (well, anyway the while does that).

**Edit**

Does your adm.exe needs TRIGGER written in UTF-16? Because that's what you're sending if you use `getBytes()`. If you need another encoding (like UTF-8 or ASCII) try with `getBytes("UTF-8")` by example.

**Sample**

I should do something like:

```
public void execute() {

String cmd = "\\\\sharedLocation\\server\\adm.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);     

// send TRIGGER before everything (I can't consume the response if I don't ask for it first)
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
out.write("TRIGGER".getBytes());
out.flush(); // flush to ensure it's sent, but don't close...

InputStream in = p.getInputStream();

String output = "";
int c = 0;
while (!output.endsWith(">")){
    c = in.read(); // you've eaten this when modified your code
    output+= (char)c; // I should change the way bytes convert to char, but that's another story
}

System.out.println(output);


// optional: if I want to wait for p to finish
p.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: yeah you are right. I've changed the condition for while but strangely still it doesn't execute the loop as you said. Any guesses why?

Comment: I wasn't complaining about the condition, but about placing the while *before* sending `TRIGGER`. I'll put an example...

Comment: I've added a detail: use `flush` not `close`

Comment: And... the adm.exe only needs `TRIGGER`? doesn't it need `TRIGGER\n`, `TRIGGER\r\n` or something? Maybe it's reading lines...

Comment: why don't you use expectj for such tasks? it would be much easier?